# Why is abstractive SERVER variables importnat?

Tags: php, oop, superglobals

I see in some PHP applications, namely in MVC frameworks a class names `Http` or `namescape application_name\http` which simple does nothing more that take the `SERVER` variable and just returns informations such as `PHP_SELF` or `REQUEST_URI` my question is why is this needed?

Comment: Typically to handle unit testing, making testing of any functions that need access to that data independent of the actual values in $_SERVER by allowing mocking of those values

Comment: @MarkBaker Ok. That makes sense. but you could somehow override the SERVER variable by a simple hack and mock the outcome. I haven't tested it, but would you say it is doable?

Comment: In addition to what Mark said, certain `$_SERVER` variables are server-specific - they act differently under Apache/nginx/lighttpd/IIS. Abstracting them away would allow the developers to provide better implementations in the future without breaking the existing interface.

Comment: You could, but most frameworks provide a standardised way of working with popular testing frameworks like phpunit so that everything is mockable in the same way, rather than having different mocking methods for user defined classes, and the system